# Highcharts3 change symbol color(symbolStroke) for export button on hover

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts3 the export button uses states.hover or states.select to extend default behavior. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/navigation/buttonoptions-theme/) shows how to change the button background color and border color. I tried to use it to change the symbol color, but no luck:

```
theme: {
    states : {
        hover : {
            symbolStroke: '#4572A5'
        },
        select : {
            symbolStroke: '#4572A5'
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to change the color of the symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is possibly bug, so I reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2218

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
 buttonOptions: {
            theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'silver',
                r: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#bada55'
                    },
                    select: {
                        stroke: '#039',
                        fill: '#bada55'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

From Highchart API  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/navigation/buttonoptions-theme/